# Can one find questions with accepted answers?

Tags: support, search, accepted-answer

I know you can find unanswered, but is there an easy way to find questions with an accepted answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by selected you mean accepted, slip this into your search:

> [hasaccepted:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A1)

For more like this, simply [consult the ninjas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: Sweet.---------

Comment: Very sweet indeed, I only just realized the `ninjas` are sneaking around.