# View only questions that have accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one find questions with accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28088/can-one-find-questions-with-accepted-answers)

As a new programmer, I am mostly interested in seeing questions that already have accepted answers (especially from my favorite tags). Is there an option to view like that?

Comment: See [Can one find questions with selected answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28088)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Next time, flag as dupe :)

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles: Way ahead of you; but flagging doesn't add a comment, only voting to close does and I don't have the MSO rep for that yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You did? Then it would have shown up in the 10k queue. If someone handled it, then the question would have a close vote. Bug? O_0

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles: Yup, I double checked and got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uAFXi.jpg

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Maybe the flag was deemed invalid by another 10k. That seems like the only other route :S

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles: Not sure about how many would need to dispute it vs. agree with it, but the flag is now marked as 'helpful' in my flags overview (I'm 59 for 59 currently).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/511/discussion-between-manishearth-wants-more-waffles-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, there is. Just add `hasaccepted:1` to your search and it'll only return questions with accepted answers.

This is nicely documented on the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search); there are a few other options you might be interested in, such as `closed:0`.